# Recovering from bootloop/can't boot in Android-x86 OS

Tags: recovery-mode, android-x86

I asked this question on Super User, but with no luck and no answers, and was advised to post here, to get help from Android specialists.

I installed several Android-x86 OS, to play with them, and to test which one is the best for my needs, Bliss OS, Prime OS, Phoenix OS...

I'd like to know what is the safer way to play with the build.prop for instance.
If I break something, and goes in bootloop, it's tiring to reinstall everytime.

I already had a bootloop because of the build.prop editing, and one because I tried to install Xposed. I had to reinstall, as I don't know how to repair my system.

There is no recovery software or recovery mode existing right now for the x86-based distros. Not even an APK to test the build.prop conformity, backup it, or letting the ability to restore it, (surprisingly).

I used Android emulator before, like Memu, and it has the very clever feature to let me save my virtual machine session each time, make copies and export them.

So, my question is how to find a way to recover my system.

Could I try to repair a bootloop from a live CD with another system for instance?
How to repair bootloop from editing wrongly system files (build.prop)? Could I do a script or something to automatize the backup of important system files, like it's the case on other system (Windows recovery, Linux backup solutions...).

Or, at least, if nobody though about that, I'd like to be able to save my configuration, so, if I reinstall, I could at least find my configuration again.

I know how to backup apk, I do that with Titanium and other tools, but what about the configuration

Comment: the reason you won't get answer most people use android on mobile devices